# Multiple Render Borders in Cycles Preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-border

Is it possible to specify multiple disjunct render borders?

[image: trivial example]

I realize that this is trivial when rendering but it would be very useful when previewing on a less-powerful computer.  I have two complex meshes on separate sides of the scene and would like to preview them both at once.

Comment: Do you mean when using cycles preview, or just set the rendering to two different places for a test render?

Comment: Using Cycles preview - edited to reflect that

Comment: best question I have seen in awhile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible currently, you can only have one renderborder per 3D view.

However, you can have multiple 3D views, each with it's own renderborder:

[image]

Note that you can only have one camera renderborder which is global for all cameras, so this is only possible in viewport render.

Comment: A great workaround - this is perfectly sufficient.